# Как изменить значение в ячейке Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть **DataGrid** связанный с БД и в нем есть два столбца: логин и пароль, которые надо рандомить при щелчке по ним (можно и через кнопку внутри ячейки). Метод рандом написан, но не получается вставлять результат в ячейку, подскажите как сделать. Вот где сейчас **TextBox** теоретически надо сделать ячейку из **DataGrid**.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox.Text = Random(str);
}

public string Random(StringBuilder str)
{
    str.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        str.Append(((char)rnd.Next(48, 57)).ToString() +
                   (char)rnd.Next(65, 90) +
                   (char)rnd.Next(97, 122));
    }
    return Convert.ToString(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если связь следующей структуры `DataBase`-`DataSet`-`CollectionViewSource`-`DataGrid` то:

1) Получаем ссылку на выделенную строку и "преобразовываем" ее в типа наших данных. Не знаю какой у вас класс, но по подобию:

```
var currentItem = ((myCollectionViewSource.View.CurrentItem as System.Data.DataRowView).Row as myBoxinClubDataSet.TodayViewRow);
```

2) Если нужны значения получаем их следующим образом.

```
string login = currentItem.Login;
string pass = currentItem.Password;
```

3) Если просто заменить, то

```
currentItem.Login = Random(str);
currentItem.Login = Random(str);
```

4) И в зависимости от того, что используется Table или View, нужно сохранить изменения в самой базе.

Comment: Спасибо, единственный толковый и верный ответ, а то перелопатил весь гугл и ничего или тонны строк кода, а тут красиво и лаконично